# jsonException:End of input at character 1 of

Tags: android

[image: End of input at character 1 of]

im making a listview and using JSONObject for array purposes but im getting this error i dont know how to fix it i dont even know where my exception takes place when i run my program it simply end and doesnt not show any result this is my java file i hope someone can find the exception

```
@Override
            protected ArrayList<TodayDetails> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                            // Create a new HTTP Client
                            DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            // Setup the get request
                            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts");

                            // Execute the request in the client
                            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient
                                            .execute(httpGetRequest);
                            // Grab the response
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                            new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity()
                                                            .getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                            String result = reader.readLine();
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                            JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("contact");
                            for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                               JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    today_details = new TodayDetails();
                                    today_details.setId(Jasonobject.getInt("id"));
                                    today_details.setName(Jasonobject.getString("name"));
                                    today_details.setEmail(Jasonobject.getString("email"));
                                    today_details.setAddress(Jasonobject.getString("address"));
                                    today_details.setGender(Jasonobject.getString("gender"));
                                    today_details.setPhone(Jasonobject.getInt("phone"));
                                    today_details.setHome(Jasonobject.getInt("home"));
                                    today_details.setMobile(Jasonobject.getInt("mobile"));
                                    today_details.setOffice(Jasonobject.getInt("office"));

                                    search_results.add(today_details);
                       }
        } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return search_results;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TodayDetails> search_results) {
        if(WeatherToday.this.pd != null){
            WeatherToday.this.pd.dismiss();
        }
        ArrayList<TodayDetails> today_details = search_results;
        list_view_main = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.todaylist);
        list_view_main.setAdapter(new TodayListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), today_details));
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SANITARY CHECK**
When working with JSON

Check for an error on the JSON side.
This is a useful link for json validation.

[Jsonlint](http://www.jsonlint.com)Try this link to validate your JSON,JUST COPY/PASTE YOUR JSON and check if its valid or not

If its valid then post it over here , may be then will be able to help you more.

If Its not Valid...Well then everything will just be fine :-)

**CODE CHECK**

1. Add the complete json by reading it line by line into a StringBuilder
2. Call toString and pass the resulting JSOn as a String to the JSONObject obj=new JsonObject(String) function.

   1. So Now if you get an exception then something bad in your json check it via the above mention link.
   2. If it works fine , then iterate the jsonObject for the array , array of object or whatever.

I hope you'll find this useful

## Update

Using the Gson library is quite useful as json gets bigger.It handles every thing for you.Abstract in nature, and provides some static method for you to retrieve the json or make one.

Here's a gist of a programs that i made for json parsing using Gson library.

[Gson demo programs](https://gist.github.com/raul1991/bad859e48c60f9e3fc62)

## Help articles

[Blog help](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

[Gson Official](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: it is showing me an error that is not in my code it show a mistake in package part which im sure a correct one what should i there the entire activity in which JSON is in?

Comment: Parse error on line 1:
packagecom.bpi.gears
^
Expecting '{', '[' check this out this is the error

Comment: Make sure that the class scope ends correctly(the starting and ending "}" ) or look for semi colons  .......IF STILL DOES not help you,post a screenshot of a bit of your code.

Comment: sorry it was a valid json whats next you say?how can i read it into a StringBuilder

Comment: Okay so here's how you will have to read the json into the builder.....So **StringBuilder buidler=new  StringBuilder();** while((Str=reader.readLine())!=null){ builder.append(Str);}so that now becomes a Stringbuilder object filled with json data(VALID DATA).....so Now JsonObject object=new JsonObject(builder.toString());so now you just passed the json in a json object..Now you can retrieve everything you need from the json...

Comment: let me try it mate by the way where should i put this?

Comment: JsonObject object=new JsonObject(builder.toString());
is this suppose to be 
JSONObject object=news JSONObject(builder.toString());?i change it to this no result

Comment: After you wrote that BufferedReader...put the while loop after that replace** String result = reader.readLine();with String result = builder.toString; rest seems to be fine..** and DO CHECK THE NAMES OF THE OBJECTS AND ARRAYS IN YOUR JSON,and put them correctly

Comment: so il use this JSONObject object=news JSONObject(builder.toString());?this is how i put it 

  StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(); 
                            while((Str=reader.readLine())!=null)
                            { builder.append(Str);}
                            
                           
                            JSONObject object=new JSONObject(builder.toString());

Comment: have a look at this this is what i made still no result http://pastebin.com/sDz3wb7T

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mFvKGphB  ----look at this its what i made and it runs fine..it is however just a skeleton of what u actually require but really helpful i feel so,  ALSO POST YOUR ERRORS WHAT YOU ARE FACING

Comment: its hard to code it i always get error can you look at it http://pastebin.com/9xYdRvv3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28490/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-martin-lloyd-stifler)

Comment: i wasnt able to run this is the code i used http://pastie.org/private/lfvjwtrmuwtlvo5fe0vfpa i had a no resource found error i have no more ideas left

Comment: post your logcat here.. and your adapter class

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4ANXV8bC adapter and http://s248.photobucket.com/user/guradio/media/r-1.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0 this is the logcat it no resource and can see the JSON http://pastebin.com/9a848fC6 you might want to check it i think nothing is wrong here but i cant figure it maybe this is the error

Comment: take a look at this http://pastie.org/7668832 i change a few codes and
a few changes on log cat happens http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=8673171 i just cant seem to locate the JSON do need to put name on it like http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c7d5d61

Comment: remove those extra "/" or"\" just let it be , and to be sure about your json visit **www.jsonlint.com**   and i am not getting where you are stuck as your code seems to be fine.Please elaborate the details like it seems that you can easily get to the json,so aren't these showing up in listview?

Comment: come please http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28490/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-martin-lloyd-stifler

Comment: hey me again i was able to run it thank you.can you help me with another thing how can i upload an image from url and how can i put integer there?thank you

Comment: Please elaborate your problem..i am unable to understand it.

Comment: they are all string right?i want to put integer type and an image view from url.

Comment: For integer write "somekey":133 somevalue  for an.imag i would recomend you provide a url over here from there you should yu getbthe image so like this "somekey":"someurl" get this url in your json and getvthe image using httpurlconnection class in java usong its openconnection method

Comment: http://m1332.photobucket.com/albumview/albums/cafebabe1991/SC20130422-130652_zps03e7ecbb.png.html?o=0&newest=1 check.this image for an example json

Comment: This is ashort example of json with an integer Nd url....{  counter:123,url:"www.someurl.com" }  so now getvthese two values as an int jsonObject.getInt("counter"); jsonObject.getString("url"); so now using the link use httpUrlConection class to get the image from there  ,use open method of this class to get an inputstream now use BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream) this returns you a bitmap so set it to your imageview

Comment: {
    "Count": 123,
    "Url": "ehjejejeii.com"
}

Comment: private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> i used this one i work thank you so much for all your help until my next question babe

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I can see is that you want "contacts" not "contact":

```
 JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("contact");
```

From:

```
{
"contacts": [
    {
            "id": "c200",
```

And none of that weather stuff is in that JSON either. So obviously there are many things that can fail.

*EDIT*: I see you got rid of the weather bits. Heh

*EDIT 2*: However, it seems like whatever is printing that logcat output DOES care about the weather.

*EDIT 3*: You're reading *just one line* of the JSON, which is `{`. That's not proper JSON. Read the full output.

```
   String result = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: i did because it was a test to show if i have the error in that part sorry about it but the error was the same so i crossed it out.what do you mean by want "contact" not "contact" they are just the same

Comment: Duh! contact*S* . I've fixed it.

Comment: Actually, I just saw the problem.

Comment: dmon what do you mean?tell me

Comment: So after `String result = reader.readLine();`, `result` now has the first line , which is just the open brace (`{`). You then try to parse that as JSON, but it's NOT JSON, it's just the brace. You need to read the whole content of the BufferedReader into result first.

Comment: i really have no idea what your saying.can i get any suggestions then dmon?

Comment: Uh, which part is not clear? See [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) for the proper usage of a BufferedReader. Does that help?

Comment: i can work with this to solve my problem thank you dmon salvatore lol

Comment: in the end i still cant run it can you help me with it?